# Recover files with broken inode on NTFS

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, data-recovery, ntfs

I already saved a broken hard drive using `ddrescue` to copy the entire drive to a save location. Now I got a lot of files recovered, but some video files are showing like this when doing `ls` on the directory:

[image]

I guess since the entry in the filesystem is still there, there could be a possible recovery option here. Is it possible to recover these files specifically or do I need to run scalpel on the entire disk and wait another couple of days for it to finish?
The drive is formatted with NTFS.